# incomplete type is not allowed while trying to create an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, include

I created 2 classes, Branch and Account and I want my Branch class have an array of Account pointers, but i fail to do it. It says that "incomplete type is not allowed". What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;



    class Branch{

    /*--------------------public variables--------------*/
    public:
        Branch(int id, string name);
        Branch(Branch &br);
        ~Branch();
        Account* ownedAccounts[];    // error at this line
        string getName();
        int getId();
        int numberOfBranches;
    /*--------------------public variables--------------*/

    /*--------------------private variables--------------*/
    private:
        int branchId;
        string branchName;
    /*--------------------private variables--------------*/
    };
```

Comment: Does the array have a size known at compile time? Also, are you sure you need `Account` pointers, and not just objects?

Comment: There is no error at that line, with g++. Demo: http://ideone.com/wczznf Since I don't have `"Account.h"` I instead wrote: class Account;

Comment: size of array is 0 at the beginning, and i will extend it dynamically. and yes, i need Account pointers, because array of Account object is at another file, and i need to point it also from another class named Customer.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. First of all, you can use a `std::vector` to do the resizing and everything. About your structure, if both `Customer.h` and `Branch.h` include `Account.h`, they can both use normal objects just fine. No pointers needed.

Comment: We are not allowed to use `std::vector`. And about my structure, it is a bit complex in my head that i can't explain it too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although you can create an array of pointers to forward-declared classes, you cannot create an array with an unknown size. If you want to create the array at runtime, make a pointer to a pointer (which is of course also allowed):

```
Account **ownedAccounts;
...
// Later on, in the constructor
ownedAccounts = new Account*[numOwnedAccounts];
...
// Later on, in the destructor
delete[] ownedAccounts;
```

Comment: Considering the application of the Account class, I think it will be a good idea to use a better container than a c-style raw array, with convenience functions and stuff like that. Plus it will not need manual deletion.

Comment: @ddriver This is absolutely true. However, the code in question looks like a learning assignment, so chances are the OP has not studied the containers yet.

Comment: Well, I emphasize that **YOU MUST FOLLOW THE RULE OF THREE OR FIVE**. Don't come back when it doesn't work because you ignored it.

Comment: actually, memory leak is unacceptable in our assignment so i'm going to use destructor, constructor and copy constructor.

Comment: And assignment operator, and possibly move constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the size of the array... You can't just leave the brackets hanging like that without anything inside them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, considering the example here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/ has empty brackets for ```int firstarray[]```

Comment: This was the answer that helped me. Interestingly, not specifying the size works when instantiating an array on the stack, but not when part of a class declaration. While the rationale makes sense, this was a bit surprising to me.

Comment: This was much more helpful.  I had this error with const char* arrApples[]={"1", "2", "3"}; but needed const char* arrApples[3]={"1", "2", "3"};     .... where I added the array size in my h file.